# Want to display file list last modified in JSP

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 3 and my controller is passing a List from the controller to the JSP:

List suitableMatches = new ArrayList();
...//Some code that adds Files to this list
 model.addAttribute("lists", suitableMatches);

and in my jsp :

```
<tr>
<td class="readOnly">${list.name}</td>
<td class="readOnly">${idiomSearch.testCaseID}</td>
<td class="readOnly">${list.lastModified}</td>
<td class="readOnly"><a href="downloadFile.htm?testID=${list.name}">Download</a></td>
</tr>
```

But I am getting the error :

Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'lastModified' not found on type java.io.File

Can anyone tell me please ,how is it that list.lastModified is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of the [JSP Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) that your web server is using you might not be able to access *non-getter* methods with this syntax.

`${list.name}` works as *File* has a method called [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29). However, *File* does not have a method called `getLastModified()`, the method is just called [`lastModified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) so you have to add brackets when calling a method that is not a getter.

So the code should read `${list.lastModified()}` and you will need to use at least v2.2 of the EL jar so this will need to either be included explicitly in the web application or use a servlet container that already includes this library.

A good source for the el syntax can be found in stackoverflow's [el tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: Thank you @Andy, However I created a java bean with getters only, and in the constructor , I passed the date value I needed. Because lastModified would display only long value, which would not make sense to display on the screen, so I did this :'public class SuitableMatch {
..
  ..
  private final String dateCompleted;
  ..
  public SuitableMatch(File file, String testId, String testCaseId) {..
    this.dateCompleted = new java.util.Date(file.lastModified()).toString();
..
  
  }'

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of JSTL and expression language for this like

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${file.lastModified()}"/>

<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" value="${dateValue}" />
```